# Contact form captcha showing Undefined index notices

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to implement captcha validation for a contact form. I'm getting the following error for every textbox:

`>Notice Undefined index: name in contact1.php on line 16

> Notice Undefined index: name in contact1.php on line 21
>   Notice Undefined index: name in contact1.php on line 26
>   Notice Undefined index: name in contact1.php on line 41`

**contact.php:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>PHP Contact Form with Captcha</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" style="margin:0px;  font-  family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px; width:300px;"   onsubmit="MM_validateForm('from','','RisEmail','subject','','R','verif_box','','R','message'      ,'','R');return document.MM_returnValue">

  Your Name:<br />
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;    width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"   value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"/>
 <br />
 <br />

 Your e-mail:<br />
 <input name="from" type="text" id="from" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;  width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"  value="<?php echo $_GET['from'];?>"/>
 <br />
 <br />

 Subject:<br />
 <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid  #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font- size:11px;" value="<?php echo $_GET['subject'];?>"/>
 <br />
 <br />

 Type verification image:<br />
 <input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid   #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-  size:11px;"/>
  <img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image,   type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="absbottom" /><br />
   <br />

  <!-- if the variable "wrong_code" is sent from previous page then display the error  field -->
  <?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){?>
  <div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF;   padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:295px;">Wrong verification code</div><br /> 
  <?php ;}?>

  Message:<br />
    <textarea name="message" cols="6" rows="5" id="message" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:300px; height:100px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;"><?php echo $_GET['message'];?></textarea>
    <noscript><a href="http://www.thewebhelp.com" style="display:none;">contact form by   thewebhelp</a></noscript>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" style="margin-top:10px; display:block; border:1px     solid #000000; width:100px; height:20px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   font-size:11px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px;   line-height:14px; background-color:#EFEFEF;" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**verificationimage.php**

```
  <?php


   header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  $width = 50;
  $height = 24;

   $my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

   imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

   // add noise
  for ($c = 0; $c < 40; $c++){
      $x = rand(0,$width-1);
      $y = rand(0,$height-1);
      imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
     }

  $x = rand(1,10);
  $y = rand(1,10);

   $rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
   imagestring($my_image, 5, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);

  setcookie('tntcon',(md5($rand_string).'a4xn'));

  imagejpeg($my_image);
  imagedestroy($my_image);
 ?>



  mailer.php
  enter code here
  <?php
 $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
 $subject = $_REQUEST["subject"];
 $message = $_REQUEST["message"];
 $from = $_REQUEST["from"];
 $verif_box = $_REQUEST["verif_box"];

 $name = stripslashes($name); 
 $message = stripslashes($message); 
 $subject = stripslashes($subject); 
 $from = stripslashes($from); 

 if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
  $message = "Name: ".$name."\n".$message;
  $message = "From: ".$from."\n".$message;
  mail("adriantadeo14@rocketmail.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject,     $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".$message, "From: $from");
  setcookie('tntcon','');
   } else {

   header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?  subject=$subject&from=$from&message=$message&wrong_code=true");
   exit;
  }
  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
         <title>PHP Contact Form Redirect</title>
      </head>

        <body>
       </body>
       </html>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you calling the URL ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran like this ( http://localhost/date2/captcha/php-contact-form/contact.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment , you have mentioned that you are calling the `contact.php` URL as `http://localhost/date2/captcha/php-contact-form/contact.php`

But as you can see from your code.. The `contact.php` expects `$_GET` parameters.

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;    width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"   value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"/>
```

So you need to pass those parameters along with the URL. See your line 16 as where the notice was thrown.

### The code ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>PHP Contact Form with Captcha</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" style="margin:0px;  font-  family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px; width:300px;"   onsubmit="MM_validateForm('from','','RisEmail','subject','','R','verif_box','','R','message'      ,'','R');return document.MM_returnValue">

    Your Name:<br />
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;    width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"   value=""/>
    <br />
    <br />

    Your e-mail:<br />
    <input name="from" type="text" id="from" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;  width:180px; height:14px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;"  value=""/>
    <br />
    <br />

    Subject:<br />
    <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid  #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font- size:11px;" value=""/>
    <br />
    <br />

    Type verification image:<br />
    <input name="verif_box" type="text" id="verif_box" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid   #CCCCCC; width:180px; height:14px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-  size:11px;"/>
    <img src="verificationimage.php?<?php echo rand(0,9999);?>" alt="verification image,   type it in the box" width="50" height="24" align="absbottom" /><br />
    <br />

    <!-- if the variable "wrong_code" is sent from previous page then display the error  field -->
    <?php if(isset($_GET['wrong_code'])){?>
        <div style="border:1px solid #990000; background-color:#D70000; color:#FFFFFF;   padding:4px; padding-left:6px;width:295px;">Wrong verification code</div><br />
        <?php ;}?>

    Message:<br />
    <textarea name="message" cols="6" rows="5" id="message" style="padding:2px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:300px; height:100px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;"></textarea>
    <noscript><a href="http://www.thewebhelp.com" style="display:none;">contact form by   thewebhelp</a></noscript>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" style="margin-top:10px; display:block; border:1px     solid #000000; width:100px; height:20px;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   font-size:11px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:2px;   line-height:14px; background-color:#EFEFEF;" value="Send Message"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tnx for your reply how to do that? tnx

Comment: `http://localhost/date2/captcha/php-contact-form/contact.php?name=danielcraigorwhatever` You need to pass other parameters as well. See your `<input>` controls.

Comment: so i cannot remove the NOTICE?

Comment: You can . why not ? If you passed the parameters correctly there won't be any notices !

Comment: cant understand how to pass other parameters? so the NOTICE will not show?

Comment: yah this the name change to danielcraigorw â€‹hatever other still have notice

Comment: Can you try the pasted code and just call it like `http://localhost/date2/captcha/php-contact-form/contact.php`

Comment: @user3315305, Can you start another question because it is not possible go on commenting here which is against SO rules. See here `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?` Since you do not have enough reputation you wont be able to chat, but eventually you will.

Comment: ow ok :)) tnx tnx:)) ill create one again:) tnx

Answer (score 0):

You should collect and verify the $_POST variables not the $_REQUEST

```
 $name = $_POST["name"];
```

for all variables posted from the form

Comment: John, that variables can be accessed under the `$_REQUEST` too.

Comment: @Johntaa tnx for the reply so ill change REQUEST TO post all?

Comment: @Johntaa yah even i change to post nothing happen Shankar is correct i thnk